# How can I make jQuery isotope center container and set gutter?

Tags: jquery, center, jquery-isotope, gutter

I'm trying to reproduce the container centering effect as show on [isotope's website](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/centered-masonry.html).

I had set CSS `margin: 0 auto` on the container, but the container doesn't resize (and thus doesn't get CSS `width` to work with `margin: 0 auto`).

I also set the gutter between items, and that doesn't work as well.

[Here is how I do it.](http://jsfiddle.net/IanY/4D6N9/5/)

Btw, how can I make items appears and be in position instantly (like the official website shows) instead of being "slideToggled"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you're missing the custom code that's required to add those custom methods to Isotope's prototype. If you look at the documentation for [Modified Layout Modes](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/layout-modes.html#modified_layout_modes), it says:

> To use these mods, copy the revised methods found in the demos’ page source.

Here are two fiddles showing the modified layout modes you mentioned:

Centered: http://jsfiddle.net/nate/6j5X2/

Gutters: http://jsfiddle.net/nate/4D6N9/7/

You'll notice that even on Isotope's site, the two are not shown working in combination with each other. That's because the two have mutually exclusive `_masonryReset`, `_masronyResizeChanged`, and `._masonryGetContainerSize` functions. It's not impossible that the two could work together, but they're not written to do so yet.

You also asked:

> Btw, how can I make items appears and be in position instantly (like the official website shows) instead of being "slideToggled"?

The initial animation is caused by your naming your container "isotope", which means it gets animated the first time. If you name it something different, like container (as on Isotope's demo page), it doesn't get the `isotope` class until it's been laid out the first time, which prevents an initial animation.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to make the container's `width` being dynamically adjusted like the official website shows? And also make items of different height align tidily? Currently both features can't seem to co-exist.

Comment: I aksed the author and he said centering in this case is not supported. [(reference)](https://github.com/desandro/isotope/issues/579)

Comment: In [my first example](http://jsfiddle.net/nate/6j5X2/), the container's width is dynamically adjusted.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, `layoutMode: 'fitRows'` doesn't work with that.